# AS3: The expression on the right side of the is operator must be a class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, exception

```
        public static const DIAGONAL_HEURISTIC:Function = function (tile:IAstarTile, req:PathRequest):Number {
        var start:Point = (tile as IPositionTile).getPosition();
        var end:Point = (req.getEnd() as IPositionTile).getPosition();

        var xd:int = Math.abs(end.x - start.x);
        var yd:int = Math.abs(end.y - start.y);
        if (xd > yd) {
            return diagonalMultiplier * (req.getMap() as Map).getDefaultCost() * yd + normalMultiplier * (req.getMap() as Map).getDefaultCost() * (xd - yd);
        } else {
            return diagonalMultiplier * (req.getMap() as Map).getDefaultCost() * xd + normalMultiplier * (req.getMap() as Map).getDefaultCost() * (yd - xd);
        }
    }
```

Hi, i get `exception, information=TypeError: Error #1041: RHS of operator must be a Class` on the returning. Code was taken from [repo](https://github.com/congk/Dauntless/blob/master/be/dauntless/astar/basic2d/Map.as). Why the exception may be caused?

**update:**

The error is caused by this line below :

```
(req.getMap() as Map).getDefaultCost() .... etc
```

Class `Map` implements (interface) `IMap`, but in the above line `Map` is not considered a class, and therefore using the `as` operator triggers an exception fault.

note : **This exception was triggered by AIR SDK 3.5, but was not triggered via AIR SDK 3.1**

see image :
[Debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSyC0.png)

Comment: Check if `(req.getMap() as Map).getDefaultCost()` actually returns a number, and not null or an Object of some kind.

Comment: An exception occurs at the stage of transformation: req.getMap() as Map

Comment: yes, "public class Map implements IMap"

Comment: You code is not validating any "is" operator. Can you post complete stack trace?

Comment: Its my mistake in descriptions, actual exeption dont exists is operator, original: Error #1041: RHS of operator must be a Class

Comment: @GreatBrain, What does "actual exeption dont exists is operator" mean? Just **update / edit** your question post with the real facts. What line is giving the error? Show that exact line's code. You picture hi-lights the IF statement, so are you saying checking `if ( integer xd > integer yd )` expects `yd` to be a class instead of integer??

Answer (score 0):

Class Map implements (interface) IMap. In the row: `(req.getMap() as Map).getDefaultCost()` - Map is not a class, and operator 'as' send an exeption. An exception was triggered at AIR SDK 3.5, and not triggered at the AIR SDK 3.1.